# How to bring the text of a variable into the TextField Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm a beginner in vibration and I'm trying to develop my first application.

I did a lot of research and couldn't find the answer to my question.

I am looking for the address, neighborhood and city information through the zip code using an API.

I'm storing this data in variables and I would like that, when clicking the button to search for this information, the return would occur in a TextField and not in a text, as it is now in my code.

This information I am bringing at the time of user registration and I would like to bring it in a standard layout.

Here is my code ...

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'dart:convert';


    class cadastro extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _cadastroState createState() => _cadastroState();
   }

   class _cadastroState extends State<cadastro> {
   String _logradouro = "";
   String _localidade = "";
   String _bairro = "";

   TextEditingController _controllerCep = TextEditingController();

   _recuperarCep() async {
   String cepDigitado = _controllerCep.text;
   String url = "http://viacep.com.br/ws/${cepDigitado}/json/";
   http.Response response;

   response = await http.get(url);
   Map<String, dynamic> retorno = json.decode(response.body);
   String logradouro = retorno["logradouro"];
   String bairro = retorno["bairro"];
   String localidade = retorno["localidade"];

setState(() {
  _logradouro = "${logradouro}";
  _localidade = "${localidade}";
  _bairro = "${bairro}";
});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
          child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Cep",
                    style: (TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff4f4138),
                      fontSize: 20,
                    )),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Color(0xffffdb2e),
                      textColor: Color(0xff4f4138),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: Text(
                        "Buscar",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: _recuperarCep,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
              child: TextField(
                maxLength: 8,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff4f4138),
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  fillColor: Color(0xff4f4138),
                ),
                controller: _controllerCep,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, bottom: 30, top: 30),
              child: Text(
                "Logradouro: " + _logradouro,
                style: (TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff4f4138),
                  fontSize: 20,
                )),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, top: 20),
              child: Text(
                "Bairro: " + _bairro,
                style: (TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff4f4138),
                  fontSize: 20,
                )),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, top: 20),
              child: Text(
                "Cidade: " + _localidade,
                style: (TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff4f4138),
                  fontSize: 20,
                )),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
     ));
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code for you this should be what you are looking for

```
TextEditingController _controllerLogradouro = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _controllerBairro = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _controllerCidade = TextEditingController();
//Initialize this with your other TextEditingController

setState(() {
      _controllerLogradouro.text = "Logradouro: ${logradouro}";
      _controllerCidade.text = "Cidade: ${localidade}";
      _controllerBairro.text = "Bairro: ${bairro}";
    });

Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Cep",
                    style: (TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff4f4138),
                      fontSize: 20,
                    )),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Color(0xffffdb2e),
                      textColor: Color(0xff4f4138),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: Text(
                        "Buscar",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: _recuperarCep,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                child: TextField(
                  maxLength: 8,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff4f4138),
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    fillColor: Color(0xff4f4138),
                  ),
                  controller: _controllerCep,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, bottom: 30, top: 30),
                child: TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff4f4138),
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                  controller: _controllerLogradouro,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, top: 20),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: _controllerBairro,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff4f4138),
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, top: 20),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: _controllerCidade,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff4f4138),
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

I think I put your variables in the right place sorry if I didn't I only speak english

Comment: Your welcome if it worked can you accept and upvote the answer in case other people have the same issue it will help them in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the 3 Text elements to TextField.
2. Define 3 TextEditingControllers and assign them to the TextFields.
3. In your recuperarCep method, instead of setting the variables to the obtained values, set the corresponding TextField's controller's 'text' property to the value.

Answer (score -1):

assuming that you are inside your function:
add this line

```
setState((){
_controllerCep.text = _logradouro.toString();
});
```

now whatever the value of your _logradouro variable is the value in your textfield